# Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my WhiteSpaceCounter code?

Tags: java, io, whitespace

I need a program that counts the whitespace in a text document, but it keeps giving me an insane number of whitespaces, as I think the while loop just keeps repeating. could anyone read it over and tell me what is up?

```
import java.io.*;
public class WhiteSpaceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("excerpt.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inreader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inreader);
        String sentence;
        int countWords = 0, whitespaceCount = 0;
        while((sentence = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] wordlist = sentence.split("\\s+");
            countWords += wordlist.length;
            whitespaceCount += countWords -1;
        }
        System.out.println("The total number of whitespaces in the file is: "
                            + whitespaceCount);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use this

```
    while((sentence = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] wordlist = sentence.split("\\s+");
        whitespaceCount += wordlist.length-1;
    }
```

Comment: this works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you first line has 3 word and your second line has 10 words, then you logic is

```
countWords (0) += 3 -> 3

countWords(3) += 10 -> 13
```

So do not use +=

```
countWords = wordlist.length;
```